# How do I implement <pre> with tinymce

Tags: tinymce

Glad to see a lot of posts about tinymce but there's nothing here that helps me with my current problem.

What I am trying to do is work out how to add "code" to my text with tinymce.

```
Something like this
```

Does anyone know how I can do this.

Help would be appreciated.

Mandy

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add `pre` to the tinymce init setting [valid_elements](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3avalid_elements)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add to the editor the **Code Sample plugin** to your editor.

This is the example code to include the plugin from the TinyMCE website.

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: "textarea",  // change this value according to your HTML
  plugins: "codesample",
  toolbar: "codesample"
});
```

The **codesample plugin** uses http://prismjs.com/ to embed the code samples within the editor and works out of the box. That is, when a user copies valid code syntax into the editable area the code will be automatically formatted according to Prism default CSS rules.

> You need to add **prism.js** and **prism.css** to your page for syntax highlighting to work.

Then you will get the code sample button in your editor interface.

[image: Code sample TinyMCE buttons]

Here you can find the [Documentation](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/codesample/) about.